# execute C# event handler and after that js function

Tags: c#, javascript, onclick, onclientclick

I have button:

html:

```
 <asp:Button ID="MyBut" runat="server" OnClick="MyBut_Click" CssClass="MyBut" />
```

C#:

```
 protected void MyBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {....}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".MyBut").click(function () { alert("!"); });
})
```

Now js function is executed first,  after that C# method is executed .
 Can C# method be first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. The C# method is called in code-behind (you are using ASP.NET), and that gets called only upon page reload when the server executes the back-end code to form the updated page.

What you could do is to have the server-side code (the C# code) generate client-side JavaScript that would then be executed as the page reloads in the user's browser. That code would then be executed, of course, after the server-side C# code. See [Inject Javascript from asp.net code behind files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046565/inject-javascript-from-asp-net-code-behind-files) for an example.

Another option would be that you use AJAX to call the server-side code (so instead of code-behind). Then you can determine the sequence yourself. For more on AJAX with ASP.NET, see http://www.asp.net/ajax.

Comment: How can I change div innerHtml (I think that I need js) after MyBut_Click was executed?

Comment: See the 2nd paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So someone clicks a button on a page, the JS fires first and then the C#? This is the only possible sequence of events. The JS on the page that handles the click of the HTML button, fires the event to the web server, and then C# runs on the web server.