# Implementing JavaScript/jQuery to control Repeater with Carousel in Kentico

Tags: kentico

I wanted to know if I can control or customise the web part repeater with carousel properties using a JavaScript/jQuery ? such as speed or easing or the way the images aligned

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a repeater web part for a carousel in Kentico and you want to be able to set the values for the carousel properties in the repeater configuration you can [clone the repeater web part](https://docs.kentico.com/k8/custom-development/developing-web-parts/customizing-web-parts), add the carousel properties into the cloned repeater web part code, and into the Fields in the web part properties. Then you would pass those properties to the front end as javascript variables using [RegisterClientScriptBlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046565/inject-javascript-from-asp-net-code-behind-files)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the speed in the initalization script property, just add something like `speed: 500`

You can read the [documentation](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/documentation.php) to see what all you can do with that carousel.

Comment: I tried modifying the intialization script, but it is not being reflected

Comment: @RonyJoseph did you do it in the web part property?

Comment: Yup, tried different settings like speed, easing etc, doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

I have done this multiple times. This is what I would suggest you

1. Create Page type for your slides Bind it with a repeater (Not basic
   repeater)
2. For markup use Slick slider. It's one of the best library
   to create slider which are responsive too

You can do anything possible using this slider. I have done all sort of crazy things with slick slider. Let me know if you need any more help on this.

[Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Comment: I see what you are saying, but i am not able to make any changes to the existing carousel using javascript file, nothing seems to affect!

Comment: Also, sorry i didnt mention, I am working on an existing project of a firm, they have this carousel, which i think works entirely based on the kentico cms interface properties. What i wanted to accomplish is i have to reposition the carousel differently in different months.