# Response.Write is not adding a <script> tag to my HTML

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET WebForms app where I'm generating some HTML code using `Response.Write` in VB.NET. However I want to add some validation code:

```vb
' add jQuery validator for mandatory fields
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>")
Response.Write("mandatoryAdditionalFieldRules = Object.assign(mandatoryAdditionalFieldRules, {")
Dim mandatoryAdditionalFieldsStrings As New List(Of String)
For Each q As String In MandatoryAdditionalFields
    mandatoryAdditionalFieldsStrings.Add(q & ": {required: true}")
Next
Response.Write(String.Join(", ", mandatoryAdditionalFieldsStrings))
Response.Write("});")
Response.Write("</script>")
```

This is a list of fields that is read by a JavaScript function to make sure that all those fields are filled in:

```
jQuery("#formEdit").validate({
rules: Object.assign({
    InitialDate: {
        required: true,
        date: true
    },
}, mandatoryAdditionalFieldRules),
messages: {
    InitialDate: "Enter the Initial Date",
}});
```

My problem is that this script is not being rendered in the output HTML in my browser, and thus the JavaScript code doesn't know to validate the mandatory fields. I stepped through the VB.NET code and I see where it is being called. Why would the JavaScript not appear in my browser when I'm calling `Response.Write` to write it out? Other content of the page containing this code is being rendered. It's just the JavaScript I added that's not rendering.

edit: could this have something to do with the fact that this page is loaded via an AJAX call?

```
jQuery('#ClientCareVisitationContactTypeAdditionalFields').load('../AdditionalField/AdditionalFieldDisplayHTMLContactType.aspx', {...}, function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
    if(statusTxt == "success"){
        // do stuff
    };
    if(statusTxt == "error")
        alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
});
```

Comment: Response.Write is usually the wrong way to do things in ASP.NET. [Inject Javascript from asp.net code behind files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7046565/1115360) shows the intended way.

Comment: I tried `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` as well, but the script still never appears on the page.

Comment: Which event handler are you using to add your script (e.g. .Load or .Init or ...)?

Comment: How the framework outputs to the page has nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.  Edited tags.  Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's not in any event handler; it's just a VB.NET script that runs on the page in `<% %>` tags.

Comment: I tried refactoring the code that was in the page into a `Page_Init` handler but still the JavaScript never gets injected into the page...

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: TL;DR**

> Response.Write is not adding a  tag to my HTML

`Response.Write` works fine. The script is added to the page and executed. You can see it in the *Elements* tab by pressing Ctrl+Shift+I in your browser. For this to work, **make sure** you do not have syntax errors in the page's JavaScript code **and** the JavaScript code generated by `Response.Write`. Also make sure you find the right place to load the code as explained below:

**Original Answer**

I am not sure why you expect that code to work.

IMHO, it is fragile code whose greatest weakness is that you set a JavaScript variable (`mandatoryAdditionalFieldRules`) through AJAX-loaded content and you expect it to be available to the (other) part of the JavaScript code found in the page. I can tell you this will only work based on luck even though I am not sure exactly when the AJAX call takes place. You can probably see it for yourself by checking the browser's console for a 'is not defined' error.

Also, the code `mandatoryAdditionalFieldRules = Object.assign(mandatoryAdditionalFieldRules, {"` won't work unless `mandatoryAdditionalFieldRules` has already been assigned a value; based on your example you can probably change it to `mandatoryAdditionalFieldRules = Object.assign({}, {"`.

If you do insist on that approach I think the safest place to set the validation rules is in the jQuery's `load` callback function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#ClientCareVisitationContactTypeAdditionalFields')
        .load('AdditionalFieldDisplayHTMLContactType.aspx', function () {
            $('#formEdit').validate({
                rules: Object.assign({
                    InitialDate: {
                        required: true,
                        date: true
                    }
                }, mandatoryAdditionalFieldRules),
                messages: {
                    InitialDate: "Enter the Initial Date",
                }
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmm... Problem is we have lots of different types of additional fields, and lots of web forms, so I'm not sure that manually loading just one of the additional field types (the ClientCareVisitationContactTypeAdditionalFields) is going to help here; I feel like loading just that one will break something on the forms where it is not used.

Comment: @ekolis What? The example is **based on yours** with the exception of including only a dummy field instead of iterating the MandatoryAdditionalFields collection which I don't know anything about. Everything else is based on your OP so I don't understand where the problem is!

Comment: Sorry, it's hard sometimes to distill a problem down to the basics, then expand an explanation of the solution back to fit into the original problem. Not your fault or mine, that's just how it is!

Comment: @ekolis I've updated the answer. I hope you understand.